# Node as field in content-type

Tags: 7, nodes

I have one type of custom node called "Concerts", and another type called "Conductors".  I would like to add a field to Concerts indicating which conductor led the concert.  However, the field types I can select from are just the basic things like Date, Float, Integer, Text, etc. - nothing about references to other nodes.

The reason this would be nice is that I assume it would let me generate content like "also led by this conductor" on the concert pages, and "concerts by this conductor" on the conductor pages.

Is this something I can accomplish with a Module?  I haven't found one yet that seems to fit the bill.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference

Comment: Thanks @leymannx, I would accept this as an answer if you want to turn it into one, or mark as a duplicate question if applicable.

Comment: Nah, it's fine. Asking for module recommendations is considered off-topic. So I won't give an answer to your question as I play the rules rather strictly. But maybe you want to answer your question yourself. Then link the module and maybe blockquote that module's description.